# How do you prevent database changes inside a Rails ActiveRecord before_create filter from getting rolled back when it returns false?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions, rollback, before-filter

I've added a before_create filter to one of my Rails ActiveRecord models and inside that filter I'm doing some database updates.

Sometimes I return false from the filter to prevent the creation of the target model, *but* that is causing all the *other* database changes I made (while inside the filter) to get rolled back.

How can I prevent that?

**Update #1**: Here's some pseudo code explaining my problem:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :update_instead

  def update_instead
    if some_condition?
      update_some_record_in_same_model # this is getting rolled back
      return false # don't create a new record
    else
      return true # let it continue
    end
  end
end
```

**Update #2**: Some good answers below but each had its shortcomings.  I ended up overridding the create method like so:

```
def create
  super unless update_instead? # yes I reversed the return values from above
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had to do this recently. You need to specifically request another connection from AR. Then execute your changes on that connection. This way, if the creation fails and rolls back the transaction, your callback's changes were already committed in a different transaction.

Ignore my answer above. The example code you just gave really clarified things.

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :update_instead

  def update_instead
    dbconn = self.class.connection_pool.checkout
    dbconn.transaction do
      dbconn.execute("update foos set name = 'updated'")
    end
    self.class.connection_pool.checkin(dbconn)
    false
  end
end


>> Foo.create(:name => 'sam')
=> #<Foo id: nil, name: "sam", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
>> Foo.all
=> [#<Foo id: 2, name: "updated", created_at: "2009-10-21 15:12:55", updated_at: "2009-10-21 15:12:55">]
```

Comment: "You need to specifically request another connection from AR" - Fantastic; how do I do that? Thanks.

Comment: heh, that might have helped. I went back and checked and unfortunately what I was doing may be slightly different. The changes I needed to persist were in a different model. So I simply told the other model to use it's own connection.

So, lets say the main transaction was on model Foo and in a before_create it did Bar.create. Even if the work on Foo failed I wanted the Bar to stick around. So I used establish_connection in the body of Bar like:

    class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
      establish_connection
    end

Comment: Yeah that's not going to work for me. I'm working with a single database here, and as you can see it my comments to the other response, nested transactions aren't working either. This is not looking good.

Comment: I'm working with a single database as well. My solution simply uses a separate connection, which brings with it a completely different transaction, for a specific model.

Comment: Here's a pastie that demonstrates what I'm very bad at putting into words. http://pastie.textmate.org/private/9qc8ckyqvyuc8s8fbnqnng

Comment: Thanks but that's not working for me.  Please see my update to the question with the example code.

Comment: I tried this technique with Rails 3.2, using AR objects instead of execute("SQL") and could not get it to work.  The transaction still got rolled back - which I think might mean it was nested in the other transaction?  Still not sure if I understand this cycle so I moved the logic into my controller.

Answer (score 2):

Use a transaction in the filter.

Comment: Thanks. Could you be a little more explicit? Perhaps some sample/pseudo code?

Comment: This doesn't work. The wrapped transaction gets rolled back with the wrapping transaction. From the documentation: "Most databases don’t support true nested transactions. At the time of writing, the only database that we’re aware of that supports true nested transactions, is MS-SQL. Because of this, Active Record emulates nested transactions by using savepoints."

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried overwriting create/save and their destructive versions? ActiveRecord::Base.create, ActiveRecord::Base.save and their destructive versions are wrapped in a transaction, they're also what trigger callbacks and validations. If you're overriding it, only the stuff done by super will be part of a transaction. If you need yo run validations before then you can explicitly call valid to run them all.

Example:

```
before_create :before_create_actions_that_can_be_rolled_back

def create
  if valid? && before_create_actions_that_wont_be_rolled_back
    super
  end
end

def before_create_actions_that_wont_be_rolled_back
 # exactly what it sounds like
end

def before_create_actions_that_can_be_rolled_back
 # exactly what it sounds like
end
```

Caveat: With these modifications the methods will be called in this order:

2. before validation (on_create)
3. validate
4. after validation (on_create)
5. before_create_actions_that_wont_be_rolled_back
6. before validation (on_create)
7. validate
8. after validation (on_create)
9. before save callbacks
10. before create callbacks
11. record is created
12. after create callbacks
13. after save callbacks

If any validations fail or if any callback returns false in steps 5-12 the database will be rolled back to the state it was in before step 5.

If valid? fails, or before_create_actions_that_wont_be_rolled_back fails than the whole chain will be halted.

Comment: That's clever and might make a great Plan B but I really need to apply the updates at the before_create step (#6 in your list) after validation. Thanks.

Comment: There's no reason you can't call valid? explicitly. That will ensure all validations pass before doing your actions that should not be rolled back. Of course it means validations will be run twice. Regardless the solution has been updated to address your concern.

Answer (score 0):

Could those changes be done in an `after_create` instead?

Comment: No I have to prevent the create in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the same concept as Rich Cavanaugh's answer. I added a parent model so it's clearer what the filter is doing. The key is to use a thread + an automatic check-out/check-in of a separate connection. Note: you should make sure your :pool value is set to at least 2 in your connection specification, depending on how many concurrent threads you'll run. I think it defaults to 5.

```
class Gadget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :widgets
end

class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :gadget
  before_create :update_instead

  def update_some_record_in_same_model
    # the thread forces a new connection to be checked out
    Thread.new do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.with_connection do |conn|
        # try this part without the 2 surrounding blocks and it will be rolled back
        gadget.touch_count += 1
        gadget.save!
      end
    end.join
  end
  def some_condition?
    true
  end

  def update_instead
    if some_condition?
      update_some_record_in_same_model # this is getting rolled back
      p [:touch_count_in_filter, gadget.reload.touch_count]
      return false # don't create a new record
    else
      return true # let it continue
    end
  end
end
```

Test:

```
  g = Gadget.create(:name => 'g1')
  puts "before:"
  p [:touch_count, g.reload.touch_count]
  p [:widget_count, Widget.count]

  g.widgets.create(:name => 'w1')
  puts "after:"
  # Success means the count stays incremented
  p [:touch_count, g.reload.touch_count]
  p [:widget_count, Widget.count]
```

Further reading: http://bibwild.wordpress.com/2011/11/14/multi-threading-in-rails-activerecord-3-0-3-1/